# When I am trying to make a game in PyGame the window will not come up

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH = 800
SCREENHEIGHT = 800
RED = (255,0,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))

pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (400, 400, 20, 20),0)
screen.fill(RED)




pygame.display.update()
```

I am trying to complete an assignment but the window will not pop up so I cannot see my game.

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop. Otherwise your program will finish without showing.
Basic example:

```
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.events.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    # here comes your game logic
    pygame.display.update()
```